# Sequelize find in JSON field

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have PostgreSQL database with JSON type field named "data" that has following content structure:

```
{
  "requestData" : {
    "url": "some url"
    "body": {
      "page_id": 12
    }
  }
}
```

I try to make `findAll` query request with filter by `page_id` using Sequelize, but don't get some results.

The question is: could I search by nested field in JSON type, or only in JSONB type? And how?

Comment: Why donot you try querying via Sequelize as raw query? It will be easy for you to search in MYSQL query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/other-data-types/#jsonb-postgresql-only) link
You can approach the answer via 3 ways:

## Nested Key

```
{
  "meta.audio.length": {
    [Op.gt]: 20
  }
}
```

## Nested object

```
{
  meta: {
    video: {
      url: {
        [Op.ne]: null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Containment

```
{
  "meta": {
    [Op.contains]: {
      site: {
        url: 'http://google.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provided link to Sequelize docs doesn't work, here is the updated one: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/other-data-types.html#jsonb--postgresql-only-

Comment: @Simon Thank you, I will update the link in the answer.